# ie 8 browser issure div comes next line

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

in ie8 the span tags are coming down they are not in the same line
how to fix it..
i changed the width its not working

http://jsfiddle.net/DA9gK/26/

```
<div style="height: 54px;">
          <span class="companyLogo">Company LOGO</span>
          <span class="quotes" style=" ">Quotes</span>
          <span class="saleOrders" >Sale Orders</span>
          <span class="invoice">Invoice</span>
          <span class="openAr" >Open AR</span>
          <div style="margin-left:592px; ">
            <span class="payments" style=" height: 21px; width: 94px;">Payments</span>
            <span class="createMemos" style=" height: 21px; width: 94px;">Create Memos</span>
            <span class="rma" style=" height: 21px; width: 94px;">RMA</span>
            <span class="crm" style=" height: 21px; width: 94px;">CRM</span>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of div.container is set to 1000px by bootstrap.css.
The left margin of the second div (containing spans) is 592px.
The width of the span content plus the left margin is greater than 1000px and so it wraps spans to the next line.

To demonstrate, I overwrite the container width to "auto !important".

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:auto !important;      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/

EDIT:
Another demonstration, I adjusted the left margins on those spans:

```
.quotes {
  ...
  margin-left: 400px;
}

element.style {
  margin-left: 552px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3QTny/

Consider using floats instead of left margins.

Comment: Same sort of issue. Check out the width of div.span3. It's far too narrow. http://jsfiddle.net/HA3aj/ You might be better off starting fresh and structuring things differently instead of hacking away at it. Especially if this is for mobile devices, which can be finicky! Also, this issue is not exclusive to IE8.